# How to tell PhpStorm type of variable with abstract factory method?

Tags: php, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have an abstract class like this

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    /** 
     * @return AbstractClass
     */ 
    public static function forge($data)
    {
        return new static($data);
    }
}
```

and another class that inherits it

```
class OtherClass extends AbstractClass
{
    public function my_method()
    {
        echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

When I make a call like

```
$otherClass = OtherClass::forge($otherclass_data);
```

PhpStorm will not autocomplete `my_method()`, and in fact pops up an error:

```
Method 'my_method' not found in class 'AbstractClass'
```

Is there any way I can force PhpStorm to know that I forged an `OtherClass`, not an `AbstractClass`?

Comment: .. but your `forge` method does not return anything anyway ... Plus, using `$this` inside the static method...

Comment: you're right, wrote as a quick example, I've edited it to make my question more clear

Comment: Not sure where you're getting that error? I ran your example and the warning it gives has nothing to do with the class abstraction. It won't autocomplete `OtherClass::my_method` because my_method is not static and should not be referenced statically. If you instantiate an OtherClass, eg `$otherClass = new OtherClass();` and type `$otherClass->` it will give autocomplete suggestions for both `forge` and `mo_method`. Can you provide an example that actually results in that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@return static` in such cases, e.g.

```
abstract class AbstractClass
{
    /** 
     * @return static
     */ 
    public static function forge($data)
    {
        return new static($data);
    }
}
```

This way it will be resolved to the calling class.

**P.S.**
Similarly `@return $this` can be used for non-static methods.

**P.P.S.**
Please note that in some not-so-simple cases (e.g. using some method of one class that has such `@return` (static or $this) in another method of another class that also use such approach) may lead to IDE confusion which will produce false warnings -- it's an IDE issue and hopefully will be resolved in one of the future releases.

Comment: Ah, seems like in my case the ide is confused.